# How to configure Wordpress Multisite by bash script?

Tags: multisite

I apologize if it's not the right place but I don't know where to ask my question.

I've searching the whole web to find a bash script that convert a single site install to a multisite install.
Using this : http://wp-cli.org/commands/core/multisite-convert/, it seems it possible but as I'd like to use a script that can easily change if i need to.

Do you know if one exists?

Comment: I'd recommend wp-cli and writing a custom class for it if it doesn't do exactly what you want :)

Comment: You already found what you need - wp-cli. Multisite-convert an one line command not worth of creating a bash script to just use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot of ways to my knowledge to 'convert' the website. The best solution I could suggest is by installing WordPress Multi-site freshly in a somewhere else then pull over the plugin files, theme files and uploads over to the newly installed multi-site. Then use any simple export/import plugins to pull over anything else needed like comments, posts, pages and other custom post types. This would be a much more time consuming solution but would work without risk to crashing things.

Note: Make sure on whatever solution you do pick to backup the database and files for the website in case a solution goes wrong you will have a copy to revert to on failure.